# ffmpeg UDP streaming artefacts

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, streaming

I keep looking for days to find a solution to my problem, but just can't figure it out.

So the problem is whatever settings I do in the stream through UDP multicast or unicast, I always get half screen artifacts randomly. Also through the internet it starts very slow of which first only the audio arrives and then the video.

For 1 example I have here in Linux streaming the desktop with the web browser in the kiosk and music in the background.

But always with artefacts after a time.

I know it is something in my settings, because I tried on different networks, different PCs, different OSes (Windows, Linux, also through VM)
Always the same result, doesn't matter what I change in the settings.
But if I open Chrome, and I am scrolling fast up and down, the image becomes normal. As soon as it is more static it again starts to become half blocky.

Photo - example of what it is happening

[image]

Comment: Can you guys stop editing so much the post. You actually cut from the attached photo the problem of how it behaves... The visible artefactos where the lower part of the image

Comment: Indeed... why the heck did `@It Wasn't Me` remove so much of the preview of the issue?